# Sub query within SELECT statement always returning NULL

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to write an SQL SELECT statement with a sub query. There is no error returned but I don't get the results I am expecting. The value for `r.related` is always NULL.

```
SELECT
    l.id,
    u.id as user_id,
    u.name,
    r.related
FROM
    list l
    INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = l.user_id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT COUNT(u.id) AS related, b.group_id
        FROM user u
        INNER JOIN booking b ON b.user_id = u.id
        WHERE u.id != l.user_id
        AND b. = 0) AS r ON r.group_id = l.group_id
WHERE
    l.group_id = 22
GROUP BY l.id, u.id
ORDER BY l.id
```

I am writing the sub query correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

```
SELECT COUNT(u.id) AS related, b.group_id
        FROM user u
        INNER JOIN booking b ON b.user_id = u.id
        WHERE u.id != b.user_id
        AND b. = 0
```

Look, you are joining user and booking table on `booking.user_id = user.id`

and

then you are just discarding those matching rows between these two tables in your where condition `WHERE user.id != booking.user_id`;

**It's more like you are looking the differences between `Set A` and `Set B` in `A intersection B`.  So in this case you won't find any (i.e. NULL).**

Comment: Good observation. It seems when I made a mistake when simplifying the query for SO. I have updated my query with `WHERE u.id != l.user_id`

Comment: No problem is still occurring.

Comment: Would you please share your running query without modifying it for `SO`?